# Typed service properties with Felix fileinstall under Karaf

Tags: osgi, apache-felix, apache-karaf

In my Karaf container, I usually use etc/*.cfg files to configure my services. However, I inherited a service that uses metatype and expects one of the properties to be a Long instead of a String (it crashes on a string). What technique should I do to provide such properties?

I discovered one potential solution but I've gotten stuck. Felix has an alternative syntax for .config files that has a syntax like:

```
key = type "value"
```

where "type" is a single-char code for the type (e.g. "L" for Long). I changed my filter to:

```
felix.fileinstall.filter = .*\\.(cfg|config)
```

So far so good. Via the debugger, I can see that Felix is reading the file, but the resulting dictionary comes back empty with no error. (I can't easily debug because org.apache.felix.fileinstall-3.2.2-sources.jar lacks ConfigurationHandler.java, which is shaded from another jar...)

Am I going down the right path and I should just try to fix my .config syntax? Or is this a legacy syntax that I should avoid and use some other technique instead?

**Update:** I partially solved my "empty dictionary" problem by fixing a syntax error in the .config file (it's pickier than I expected). My other question still stands: is this a good approach, or is there a better way?